# My case statement is returning 1900-01-01 for empty dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I am trying to return a result for 2 date columns based on different values like this:

```
CASE WHEN game_startA IS NOT NULL THEN game_startA 
     WHEN game_startB IS NOT NULL THEN game_startB 
     ELSE '' 
     END AS 'Game Start Date'
,
CASE WHEN game_endA IS NOT NULL THEN game_endA 
     WHEN game_endB IS NOT NULL THEN game_endB 
     WHEN COALESCE(game_endC, game_endD) IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(game_endC, game_endD)
     ELSE '' 
     END AS 'Game End Date'
```

The problem is, if the value is NULL, it is returning `1900-01-01` instead of saying NULL or just blank.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: `ELSE ''` -> `ELSE NULL`? Or just leave out the `ELSE`. Also `AS 'alias'` should be `AS [alias]` or at least `AS "alias"`. Single-quotes for aliases make it read like a string literal _and_ some forms are deprecated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand do you mean I should return `ELSE NULL` instead of `ELSE ''` ?

Comment: Data type is being determined as date. ‘’ isn’t a valid date so it converts to that

Comment: SQL Server definitely has some [interesting datetime conversion rules](https://dbfiddle.uk/puRYQLDk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic could be vastly simplified (unless there is more to it than you've shared):

```
COALESCE(game_startA, game_startB) AS [Game Start Date],
COALESCE(game_endA, game_endB, game_endC, game_endD) AS [Game End Date]
```

I don't see any need for the `CASE` expressions *or* any `ELSE` that tries to turn a date into an empty string. If `COALESCE()` gets to the end of its list and still doesn't find a non-`NULL` value, the output is what you want: `NULL`.